Stuck at installing flutter app in android studio
This specific app is not installing on my physical device. While it run well on emulator, secondly other apps run well on physical as well as emulator.

I do have internet permisssions defined
I am using some google and firebase features like signin and signup
I do have internet permisssions defined
I am using some google and firebase features like signin and signup
Its a small project with only signin and signup options.
I am using Android Studio 2022.3.1 Girrafe

Please have a look on the error:


On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.
